# how to insert images right after the step1 and then after step2 and so on in LateX

Tags: latex

I'am creating a document using Latex and I have some steps with images to put into document.
Steps are created using /item, but I want to know how to insert image exactly after each step.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your difficulty is that the images are staying where they are. This is perhaps because you're placing a figure inside a `figure` (floating) environment. This seems natural, but if you're not adding any `\caption`, you could just stick the images as-is in your document using `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

We follow these steps:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First step

  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth, height = 2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}

  \item Second step

  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth, height = 3\baselineskip]{example-image-b}

  \item Third step

  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth, height = 3\baselineskip]{example-image-c}

  \item Final step

  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth, height = 4\baselineskip]{example-image}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```